# Get each word from a line in a text file

Tags: c

I am trying to read a txt file, and I can get the line which I want, but I can not print every  words in this line one by one;

for example: the line looks like:

```
hello world 1 2 3
```

and I need print them one by one which looks like:

```
hello   
world   
1   
2   
3
```

I got the segmentation fault core dumped error

```
char temp[256]；

while(fgets(temp, 256, fp) != NULL) {
    ...
    int tempLength = strlen(temp);
    char *tempCopy = (char*) calloc(tempLength + 1, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(temCopy, temp, tempLength); // segmentation fault core dumped here；
                                     // works fine with temp as "name country"
    name = strtok_r(tempCopy, delimiter, &context);
    country = strtok_r(Null, delimiter, &context);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    printf("%s\n", country);
}
```

Can anyone help me fix the code?
Thanks!

Comment: `strncpy(temCopy` - misprint here. If this code compiles somehow, it writes to `temCopy`, not `tempCopy`. Why do you think you need to make `tempCopy` of `temp`?

Comment: Okay, I give up. Where did you copy this code from?

Comment: Have you checked whether calloc returns a NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impleted with `strtok()`

```
char *p;
char temp[256];

while(fgets(temp,256,fp) != NULL){
  p = strtok (temp," ");
  while (p != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",p);
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
}
```

If you see `man strtok` You will found

**BUGS**

> Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:
>          * These functions modify their first argument.

```
   * These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

   * The identity of the delimiting character is lost.

   * The strtok() function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe.  Use strtok_r() if this matters to you.
```

Try to make changes with `strtok_r()`

Answer (score 0):

```
While read a line from a file you can invoke the following function:

 if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {

                            puts(str);
                            token = strtok(str," ");
                            while(token != NULL)
                            {
                                    printf("%s\n",token);
                                    token = strtok(NULL," ");
                            }
                    }
```